# Connecting via Putty to Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, openssh, putty

I have Windows 8.1 on my PC and I try to connect via Putty to Ubuntu Server 16.04 set on VMware. I can ping each other and both got Internet connection but I still cannot connect to my Ubuntu by ssh via Putty.
While trying to connect setting SSH type connection on 22 port and putting Ubuntu IP adress I get in response:
`Network error: connection refused.`
[Here's a screenshot of my Ubuntu network config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgXx4.jpg)

Ubuntu Server have running OpenSSH server and both Windows and Ubuntu got firewall disabled while trying to connect.
Any sugestions what can help me are welcome.

Comment: From the server, can you do `ssh localhost`, i.e. connect to itself? If you can, then it's a network problem between the Windows machine and the Ubuntu Server. If not, you haven't correctly set up `ssh` on the server.

Comment: I can do ssh localhost so it seem some way further

Comment: Using a bridged network type might help.

Comment: I'm already using bridged type of network